# Converting Nested JSON to pandas dataframe with specific condition

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

Consider the JSON(a snippet of orignal JSON) below

```
{
    "Data": {
        "abc": [
            {
                "Month": "1990-01-01",
                "Country": "BEL",
                "Version": "12345",
                "check1": null,
                "check2": 123
            },
            { ........
            }
        ]
 }
```

To convert this to a dataframe, I would do the following

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

c = response1.json()
cs = c['Data']['abc']
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(cs), orient='records')
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Notice how I used cs = c['Data']**['abc']**; and here's my question;

Is there a way to achieve the above, without using `['abc']`. I am working on a function that deals with JSONs of similar structure, except the portion `['abc']`, where every JSON has a unique nomenclature.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are looking to pull data out a specific level in the JSON without referring to it by name?

Comment: How about `cs = next(iter(c['Data'].values()))`

Comment: @gtomer Yes, exactly. You see, I have so many JSONs to deal with that knowing the name of  that specific level is virtually impossible. If there is a way to parametrize this, that would be ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cs95 His answer in the comments worked for me. Reposting it here

```
cs = next(iter(c['Data'].values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cs=list(c['Data'].values())[0]
```

Comment: Not sure why, but seems like my code keeps running forever

Comment: What happend if you try `print(c['Data'].values())` ?

Comment: Same thing, just speculating, but does this have something to do with the size of JSON

Comment: What is the result of `type(c)`?

Comment: class 'dict';  I get this error TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable . The running forever this was due to my failing API's, that issue is fixed now